# Reaching static field declared in serialPersistentFields

Tags: java, reflection, xstream

So xstream (v1.4.8) with this line

```
private Object More ...readField(ObjectStreamField field, Class type, Object instance) {
        try {
           Field javaField = type.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
```

[more here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.8/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/SerializableConverter.java?av=f#295)
tries to reach the field named "list" (field.getName() returns "list")

```
private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = {
             new ObjectStreamField("list", VirtualFilePermission[].class)
     };
```

declared in  [org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFilePermissionCollection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss/jboss-vfs/3.2.9.Final/org/jboss/vfs/VirtualFilePermissionCollection.java) but runs into NoSuchFieldException. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ObjectStreamField` describes a field that is stored in the serialized stream. While the default mechanism will create an `ObjectStreamField` for each real instance field of a class, the possibility to override it via a `static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields` field exists exactly for the purpose to declare a list of stream fields which do *not* match the actual instance fields.

Such fields can’t be processed by the default algorithm of just reading and writing field values via Reflection. Instead, the dedicated `writeObject` and `readObject` methods are required which will read and write the stream fields and process their values.

The problem here is that the class `VirtualFilePermissionCollection` has such a mismatching field declaration, as the stream field is named `list` and the actual instance field is named `permissions`, and an appropriate `readObject` method (despite its unnecessary use of Reflection to access its field) but lacks a matching `writeObject` method. Since a dedicated `writeObject` method is missing, the default algorithm is used and fails because, as said, the fields don’t match.